# module csv with global variables, coffeescript and callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, coffeescript, global-variables

I'm using node-csv-parser by wdavidw with coffeescript. I know (or should know) about variables scope, bind, globals, but looking at this code snippet I couldn't understood what do @array varable lose its values or even be assigned.

*script.coffee:*

```cs
    require 'csv'
    find_lines = ->
        @array = []
        csv()
            .fromPath("#{__dirname}/Cities.csv", {delimiter:";"})
            .on 'data', (data, index) =>
                @array = data

    console.log @array

    find_lines()
```

Running the script.coffe:

> ➜  modules git:(master) ✗ coffee script.coffee

The code output is:

> quoted false
>   quoted false
>   quoted false
>   quoted false

When it should be (according to csv values):

> City 1
>   City 2
>   City 3

Using the *.transform* method from csv parser produces the same error.

Did I misunderstand how node-csv-parser works or any problem with this module?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with one possible implementation:

```
csv = require 'csv'

find_lines = ->
  array = []
  csv()
  .fromPath("#{__dirname}/Cities.csv", {delimiter:";"})
  .on 'data', (data) ->
    array.push data[0]
  .on 'end', ->
    console.log array

find_lines()
```

Note that you probably want something other than `array.push data[0]` in the 'data' callback.

You don't need to use `@array` here because the `array` variable is available to the 'data' and 'end' callbacks. This also eliminates the need for the fat arrow function bindings. In this implementation, the `array` variable is only visible in the scope of `find_lines` so you won't be able to log its contents from outside the function call.

Alternatively, you can make `array` visible outside of `find_lines` by moving it to the module scope like so:

```
csv = require 'csv'
array = []

find_lines = ->
  csv()
  ...
```

However, (and this is the really critical point), the `array` variable will **not** be modified until after the rest of your module code (including any calls to `console.log` outside of `find_lines`) has already executed. If this is unclear, you should brush up on the fundamentals of callbacks and execution order in node.js.

#### Other minor issues

1. `require 'csv'` should be `csv = require 'csv'`
2. `array` was not being modified with `data`, it was being overwritten on each new csv row